# How can I select or input text in any x-frame and i-frame element from Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

[I am facing this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EARsV.png)

```
Select Frame    css:iframe[id^="terminal xterm jp-Terminal-body"]
Sleep    2s    
Input Text    css:iframe[id^="terminal xterm jp-Terminal-body"]    git clone https://github.com/IshanChakraborty96/sample-test-notebook.git
Sleep    2s    
Press Keys    //textarea[@class="xterm-helper-textarea"]    Enter
```

I using this code for Jupyter terminal to clone my notebook from automation.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of errors or code. Take the time to copy, paste, and properly format the error in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've called `Select Frame`, the context is inside that frame. Any locators you use should be relative to the frame, not the document.

For example, given a page that looks something like this:

```
<iframe id='terminal xterm jp-Terminal-body">
    <input id='foo'>
</iframe>
```

... you can then access the input by first switching to the frame and then using something like `//input[@id='foo']` without including the frame as part of the locator.

Comment: If I want to use as `Element Should Be Visible` in iframe?

Comment: @IshanChakraborty: I don't understand the question. This answer shows you how. You select the frame, then call the keyword.

Comment: I want to Create a test case where when I click one element, after clicking the element using the keyword `Click Element`  then the output comes as a pop-up option that contains an iframe so after selecting the iframe by using `Select Frame`  my next step is to verify the pop-up is there in the UI and I am using `Element should be Visibile` as keyword and soo I want to confirm the element to end my test case but its failure and that ending part of verifying is an iframe.